# Razor + C# - Autocomplete and non-latin characters problems

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have an jQuery autocomplete field with non latin characters.

My Controller has this line:

```
ViewBag.EstadosDeAlma = (from e in db.EstadosDeAlma select e.Title).ToList();
```

All results in my database are raw, with no encoding.

In my Razor view I have this line:

```
var data = '@foreach (dynamic item in ViewBag.EstadosDeAlma){ @(item + " ") }'.split(" ");
```

As autocomplete function, it works really good, but when I try to search for results with stress as "á" it doesnt work.

When i look to the source code in FireFox, I have this:

```
var data = '&#225;lacre esperan&#231;osa hil&#225;ria ...
```

I need to have this source code like this:

```
var data = 'álacre esperançosa hilária'
```

Could someone help me with this one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to return results as a string, and not as a list.

When I do this, it works:

Controller:

```
var estadosDeAlma = "";

foreach (var item in db.EstadosDeAlma.ToList())
{
    estadosDeAlma += item.Title + " ";
}

ViewBag.EstadosDeAlma = estadosDeAlma;
```

View:

```
var data = '@Html.Raw(ViewBag.EstadosDeAlma)'.split(" ");
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `@Html.Raw(item + " ")` to render your content "unescaped".

Comment: I tried this line: var data = '@foreach (dynamic item in ViewBag.EstadosDeAlma){ @(Html.Raw(item) + " ") }'.split(" "); It doesnt work...

Comment: @Rubia, the correct syntax would be `{ @Html.Raw(item + " ") }`